# how to show only last child terms of a taxonomy

Tags: taxonomy, terms

I'm trying to show the only the last child terms of a taxonomy in a post.

For example, the post "Johnny Pastafrolla" has the following terms of the taxonomy "camp" selected:

- Summer Camp

  - Summer Camp 2018
  - Summer Camp 2019
- Space Camp
- Winter Camp

  - Winter Camp 2017

In this case, the displayed terms are gonna be:
*Summer Camp 2018, Summer Camp 2019, Space Camp, Winter Camp 2017*

I found a code [online](https://www.cssigniter.com/show-last-child-categories-using-the_category/) which is doing this, but for Categories.

```
add_filter( 'the_category_list', 'ci_theme_the_category_list_remove_parent_categories', 10 );
function ci_theme_the_category_list_remove_parent_categories( $categories ) {
    $categories_tmp = $categories;
    foreach ( $categories_tmp as $child_cat ) {
        foreach ( $categories_tmp as $key => $parent_cat ) {
            if ( isset( $categories[ $key ] ) ) {
                if ( cat_is_ancestor_of( $parent_cat, $child_cat ) ) {
                    unset( $categories[ $key ] );
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return $categories;
}
```

I'm trying to "adapt it" for this specific taxonomy, but I'm kind of lost.
Any hint?

Thank you

Dave

Comment: How are you displaying these terms? What function are you trying to modify? I believe what you want is not the _last_ terms but last child terms, would that be correct? Asking for the last term implies a publish date, or that you want the last item in a list which would be `Winter Camp 2017` or `Winter Camp`

Comment: yes exactly, the last child terms if there are any, otherwise the parent term (my example shows what I mean, the description doesn't quite :) )

Comment: @TomJNowell I guess I found a way. By the way, I checked your site; the post about anxiety is really interesting! :) have a nice weekend!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to display the terms with the get_the_term_list function so, since categories & taxonomy have a "similar logic", I replaced the "the_category_list"

`add_filter( 'the_category_list', 'ci_theme_the_category_list_remove_parent_categories', 10 );`

with
"get_the_terms"

`add_filter( 'get_the_terms', 'only_last_taxonomy_terms', 10 );`

and it does what I need.